# Execution plan index suggestion - difference between similar queries

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, index-tuning

I am trying to analyze queries on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Values](
    [tid] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [t] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [v] [real] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Values_Unique] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [t] ASC,
    [tid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am reviewing some *Estimated Execution Plans* using *SQL Server Management Studio*, **first query**.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Values]
WHERE  [tid] = 1
```

Displaying *Estimated Execution Plan* for this query yields:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Values] ([tid])
INCLUDE ([timestamp],[v])
```

Which, I can understand, it wants to have a quick look up by `tid`, altough I don't fully why the `INCLUDE` is suggested.

Then I tried a **second query** (another tid), which is pretty the same with another `tid`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Values]
WHERE  [tid] = 1 or [tid] = 2
```

But now, *SSMS*, doesn't suggest the previous index.

Why does *SSMS* suggests an INDEX for the first query but not for the second now although they are pretty the same ?

Should adding this suggested INDEX be helpful for both types of queries?

**EDIT:** This table has over 2 * 10^9 rows.

Comment: How many distinct values does tid take?

Comment: 8000 distinct values

Comment: And how large a % of them has the values 1 and 2?

Comment: The values are equally distributed - so 0.025%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some context**

The first things to observe is that your clustered index does not help with the lookup of the `tid` column, because `t` is the leading column in the index.

If you flipped the order of `t` and `tid` in the key, I would expect the index hint to go away and the query to run faster without adding any new indexes.

**Specific Answer**

The most likely reason that the second query plan does not suggest an index is that the new filter on `tid` picks more than around 30% of all the values in the table. When that is the case, SQL Server will generally prefer to table scan instead of seeking the index (because this is the better strategy). Hence, suggesting an index is no longer the right thing to do. Selecting two values instead of one may be exactly the tipping point of this 30% constant in the optimiser

To explore this effect, you can force the index hint to return by doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Values] WITH (FORCESEEK)
WHERE  [tid] = 1 or [tid] = 2
```

.. But please don't do this in production, only to explore the effects.

**Why the include?**

The include is there because if it wasn't, the execution would have to do this:

1. Find the value you are looking for in the newly created index on
   `tid`
2. Go to the main index (the primary key) to pick up the values
   of column `v` and `t`

The INCLUDE makes sure all the columns are contained in the index so the second step is not needed. Incidentally, this is one of the reasons why you should eschew SELECT *.

Comment: Any documentation about this 30% threshold?And if you have a covering index for all columns will  SELECT * know to use it?Thanks.

Comment: The 30% threshold is simply something you have to experiment with to find out yourself - that is how I found it. I don't think there is an "official" source for it. Joe Chang has pretty much reverse engineered all the magic constants in there, his blog is here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/

Comment: And yes.. SELECT * will know how to use the covering index. However, if you don't need all the columns, don't select them all. This way, a smaller index can often be used instead of a covering one.

Comment: +1 Thanks Thomas, do you think I should accept the suggestion ? most of the queries contains more than one `tid` in the where clause.

Comment: No, I don't think my answer is correct then. Unless your statisics are not up to date. To validate, please add the following to the question: Query plans for the two queries and the output of DBCC SHOWSTATISTICS WITH HISTOGRAM